# Returning ref cursor from oracle stored procedure by using DAAB from MS EntLib 4.1

Tags: oracle, enterprise-library, daab, ref-cursor

Is it possible to get ref cursor from oracle stored procedure by using DAAB from Microsoft Enterprise Library 4.1?

Comment: Ya sure. We are using an older version of DAAB and so far so good.

Comment: Thank you, Can you please share the sample code?

Comment: Thank you, Can you please share the sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, surely you can.

```
PROCEDURE load_all (
    p_row_start          IN     number,
    p_page_size          IN     number,

    cur_out              OUT    sys_refcursor
) AS
...
```

And on the C# side:

```
DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("my_package.load_all", paramValues))
IDataReader r = db.ExecuteReader(cmd);
...
```

RefCursor param supposed to be named "cur_out".

Answer (score 0):

DAAB does not provide a capability for us to get the Ref Cursor. The issue is System.Data.Common does not have DbType.Cursor or DbType.RefCursor type. So, there is a bit of tweaking required in the DAAB 4.1 source code. Please follow the steps provided in the following link. It works like a piece of cake.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DAAB_On_ODPNet.aspx